# Is it possible that two similar QR raw codes lead to the same place

Tags: encoding, qr-code

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question but, I've encountered a crypto scam site, I found out that they have a copy of the exactly same site but with different name, I have doubts that they are one and the same entity and when I checked their QR code, the codes that people should use to pay USDT, the codes look very similar to the eye ( I know it doesn't mean anything) but I noticed that QR codes raw data starts with same numbers about 4 of them are same and also about last 30% of raw code is identical. I checked both websites IP addresses and looked similar also IP geolocation showed they both pint to the same place, their coordinates are the same. I was wondering is it possible to have two different QR codes that lead to the same thing, in this case their USDT wallet I guess, and does the similarity in QR code prove something or could it just be a coincidence?

I just compared the two Qr codes but found nothing but raw code similarities